# issue in getView() of BaseAdapter the Viewholder is null

Tags: android, baseadapter, getview

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.vote_select_listview_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.AnnouncementDetailVoteListViewAdapter_view,
                viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView
                .getTag(R.id.AnnouncementDetailVoteListViewAdapter_view);
    }
```

convertView not null but viewholder is null because i add a new data call notifyDataSetChanged, the next action like this:

```
            mVoteItems.add(response4.data);
            notice_vote_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            viewHeightUtil.setListViewHeight(notice_vote_options_lv);
```

the problem is I need dynamic change ListView height, if annotation it then there is no problem, I find issue here:

```
public void setListViewHeight(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (listAdapter == null) {
        return;
    }

    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

        if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup) {
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
                    AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    AbsListView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();

    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: Post the full logic about getView() and notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: I find the problem at when notifyDataSetChanged i call mVoteItems.add(response4.data);
notice_vote_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
viewHeightUtil.setListViewHeight(notice_vote_options_lv);

Comment: edit problem again ,tkx

Comment: It is not a good way to set list item height out of list adapter, try to set a height param before calling nofifyDataSetChanged(), then let getView() to do the refreshment.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(convertView==null){
    LayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    viewholder =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
}
```

Try this